# How to require .class parameter to be a certain class in Java?

Tags: java, class, generics, type-safety

For example, I want to do something like:

```
public void foo(Class c){
    doSomething();
}
```

But I want the `Class c` parameter to be a class **that has implemented a specific interface**. Is there a way to enforce this at compile time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use generics:

```
public void foo(Class<? extends SomeInterface> c){
    doSomething();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Murelink has the right answer.

However

> Is there a way to **enforce** this at compile time?

It depends what you mean by "enforce".  Generics are implemented in Java using type erasure, and Java runtime type checking doesn't pay any attention to the generic type constraints.  It only checks that the type of the parameter is a `Class`.

This means:

- If the call is performed reflectively, the constraint is not enforced by the runtime when the actual call is made.
- If you write and compile some caller code with -source and -target compliance levels of 1.4 or earlier, then constraint is not enforced by the compiler.

And there is nothing you can do about either of these things.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to enforce this at compile time?

Not really, like @Stephen C pointed out, but you can type check at runtime using `SomeInterfaceInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(c)`